# npm error: silly pacote range manifest and cb() never called

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I'm getting these errors several times with **npm install** command. The project on other computer works fine. Part of my log files below:

```
 npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/-/zeparser-0.0.5.tgz
 npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser
 silly pacote range manifest for zeparser@^0.0.5 fetched in 504ms
 error cb() never called!
 error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
 error <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues></i>
```

I tried :

1. **npm cache clean --force**
2. Reinstall npm and node.js
3. Delete node_modules directory

npm version: 5.6.0

node version: v8.9.4(I installed lower node and npm versions too)

- Even node_modules folder does not exist after **npm install**.
- Why am i getting this error and what is the real solution for it?

Comment: Can you please let me know if you solved this error. ? I have been trying with multiple different aspects but none works !!!

Comment: I cannot remember what I did before @vijayakumarpsg587, but do you run commands in admin mode?

Comment: Yeah the thing is I am really not sure what causes this. I reinstalled node a couple of times and restarted my system as well. But aint sure what the problem actually is. Now I am able to resolve it, albiet not knowing what caused the issue in the first place. Thanks for getting back to me